How do I prevent a full memory dump created on JVM crash?
I was running a java application on Windows however it occasionally crashes every months due to peak traffic.To make things worse JVM automatically generated memory dumps everytime its crashes and eating disk space rapidly.Is there any JVM arguments/or any other methods to prevent it from generating full memory dumps as I don't need these many dumps?

Based on this answer you should add parameter in start command of JVM:
-XX:HeapDumpPath=/dev/null

On Windows command should be something like:
-XX:HeapDumpPath=NUL:

(the NUL is equivalent in Windows of /dev/null in UNIX and Linux)
To set zero size of core dump in entire OS (Linux) you can use this command:
ulimit -c -H 0


Really appreciate your answer however there is no /dev/null on Windows machines...Updated my question for clarification.

@AmadeuszLiu, I update my answer with Windows way
